Different combinations of overlapping features in samples
I am currently working on identifying the largest overlaps of features in samples. For this purpose, I have a data.frame with n samples. Each sample has the same features i. In addition, I have the column state which indicates whether the feature is available for the sample:
set.seed(1234)

n = 20 # samples
i = 20 # features

dat <- data.frame(
    sample = rep(x = paste0("s", 1:n), each = i),
    feature = rep(x = paste0("f", 1:i), times = n),
    state = sample(x = c(0, 1), size = n*i, replace = TRUE))

My goal is to determine number of samples (and their ids) that have 5 to 10 identical characteristics. I've tried something like:
dat |> 
    dplyr::filter(state != 0) |>
    group_by(feature) |> summarize(n = n(), .groups = "drop")

However, I do not get all possible combinations. So I was thinking of creating an analysis that is comparable to an upset plot. Do you have an approach on how to realize this?

I'm a bit confused about what you want your final output to look like - could you clarify? (It may be easier if you reduce the size of your sample data, I dont think we need all 400 observations). Good luck!

If a sample shares at least 5 characteristics with one other sample it counts towards the final count?

I'm assuming that for each sample in your data you are looking for the set of other samples which have 5 - 10 features in commmon.
I converted the feature column into a list column, where each row was a vector of features. I wrote a function to test whether 2 vectors have 5 - 10 items in common and used this with sapply() to return a vector of sample ids which have 5 - 10 features in common with the current sample.
Finally I removed any cases where a sample is matched with itself (i.e. any sample with 5 - 10 features).
If you don't want to end up with list columns, you could use unnest() on the result.
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

set.seed(1234)

n = 20 # samples
i = 20 # features

dat <- data.frame(
                  sample = rep(x = paste0("s", 1:n), each = i),
                  feature = rep(x = paste0("f", 1:i), times = n),
                  state = sample(x = c(0, 1), size = n*i, replace = TRUE))

# remove rows where state is zero and convert features to a list column
newdat <- dat |> 
    dplyr::filter(state != 0) |>
    group_by(sample) |>
    summarise(features = list(feature))

# create a function to test if 2 sets of features have 5-10 item in common
check_5_10_matches <- function(v1, v2) {
    sum(v1 %in% v2) %in% 5:10
}

# apply ths to the data
want <- newdat |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(common = list(newdat$sample[sapply(newdat$features, \(x) check_5_10_matches(x, features))])) |>
    ungroup() |>
    mutate( common =  mapply( \(x, y) x[!(x %in% y)], common , sample))

Created on 2024-05-21 with reprex v2.1.0
Or a dplyr approach:
library(dplyr)

filtered <- dat |>
  filter(state != 0) 

filtered |>
  left_join(select(filtered, sample_overlap = sample, feature), by = "feature", relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  filter(sample != sample_overlap) |>
  mutate(matches = n(), .by = c("sample", "sample_overlap")) |>
  filter(matches >= 5 & matches <= 10) |>
  summarise(overlaps_with = list(unique(sort(sample_overlap))), .by = sample)
#>    sample                                                                    overlaps_with
#> 1      s1 s10, s11, s12, s14, s15, s16, s17, s18, s19, s2, s20, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9
#> 2      s2      s1, s10, s12, s13, s14, s15, s16, s17, s19, s20, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9
#> 3      s3                    s1, s10, s12, s14, s15, s16, s17, s2, s20, s4, s6, s7, s8, s9
#> 4      s4                                   s1, s12, s14, s18, s2, s20, s3, s5, s7, s8, s9
#> 5      s5                         s1, s12, s14, s17, s18, s19, s2, s20, s4, s6, s7, s8, s9
#> 6      s6                                               s1, s10, s14, s16, s17, s2, s3, s5
#> 7      s7     s1, s11, s12, s13, s14, s15, s16, s17, s18, s19, s2, s20, s3, s4, s5, s8, s9
#> 8      s8                         s1, s10, s12, s13, s14, s17, s2, s20, s3, s4, s5, s7, s9
#> 9      s9                              s1, s10, s12, s14, s17, s2, s20, s3, s4, s5, s7, s8
#> 10    s10                                       s1, s14, s16, s17, s2, s20, s3, s6, s8, s9
#> 11    s11                                                            s1, s14, s18, s20, s7
#> 12    s12                          s1, s14, s15, s18, s19, s2, s20, s3, s4, s5, s7, s8, s9
#> 13    s13                                                             s17, s2, s20, s7, s8
#> 14    s14       s1, s10, s11, s12, s16, s17, s18, s19, s2, s20, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9
#> 15    s15                                                         s1, s12, s2, s20, s3, s7
#> 16    s16                                           s1, s10, s14, s17, s2, s20, s3, s6, s7
#> 17    s17                s1, s10, s13, s14, s16, s18, s19, s2, s20, s3, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9
#> 18    s18                                     s1, s11, s12, s14, s17, s19, s20, s4, s5, s7
#> 19    s19                                          s1, s12, s14, s17, s18, s2, s20, s5, s7
#> 20    s20 s1, s10, s11, s12, s13, s14, s15, s16, s17, s18, s19, s2, s3, s4, s5, s7, s8, s9

Created on 2024-05-21 with reprex v2.1.0

With crossprod(xtabs( you can get the pairwise number of shared features:
nms <- unique(dat$sample)
(shared <- crossprod(xtabs(data = dat[dat$state == 1, 2:1]))[nms, nms])
#>       sample
#> sample s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 s10 s11 s12 s13 s14 s15 s16 s17 s18 s19 s20
#>    s1  14  9  9  9  7  7  8  7  7   6   5   8   3   8   7   5   7   5   5   9
#>    s2   9 13  8  6  7  5  9  8  7   5   4   8   5   9   6   6   9   4   6   8
#>    s3   9  8 11  6  4  5  6  6  6   5   4   6   2   6   6   5   5   3   3   7
#>    s4   9  6  6 10  5  4  6  7  7   4   4   6   4   7   4   3   4   5   4   8
#>    s5   7  7  4  5 10  5  7  5  6   4   3   5   3   7   3   4   7   5   5   5
#>    s6   7  5  5  4  5  9  4  4  4   6   4   3   1   7   3   5   6   4   2   4
#>    s7   8  9  6  6  7  4 13  8  7   4   6   8   7   6   6   6   7   5   8   9
#>    s8   7  8  6  7  5  4  8 11  8   6   4   6   6   8   4   4   7   4   4   9
#>    s9   7  7  6  7  6  4  7  8 10   6   4   5   4   6   3   4   5   3   4   7
#>    s10  6  5  5  4  4  6  4  6  6   9   3   3   3   6   2   5   7   4   3   6
#>    s11  5  4  4  4  3  4  6  4  4   3   8   4   3   5   2   2   4   5   4   5
#>    s12  8  8  6  6  5  3  8  6  5   3   4  10   3   6   5   3   4   5   5   5
#>    s13  3  5  2  4  3  1  7  6  4   3   3   3   7   4   2   4   5   3   4   7
#>    s14  8  9  6  7  7  7  6  8  6   6   5   6   4  13   3   6   9   8   5   8
#>    s15  7  6  6  4  3  3  6  4  3   2   2   5   2   3   7   3   3   1   3   5
#>    s16  5  6  5  3  4  5  6  4  4   5   2   3   4   6   3   9   6   3   3   6
#>    s17  7  9  5  4  7  6  7  7  5   7   4   4   5   9   3   6  12   5   6   8
#>    s18  5  4  3  5  5  4  5  4  3   4   5   5   3   8   1   3   5   9   6   5
#>    s19  5  6  3  4  5  2  8  4  4   3   4   5   4   5   3   3   6   6   9   6
#>    s20  9  8  7  8  5  4  9  9  7   6   5   5   7   8   5   6   8   5   6  13

To get the samples with 5 to 10 shared features:
bln <- (abs(shared - 7.5) < 3) & lower.tri(shared)
cbind(which(bln, TRUE, FALSE)[,2:1], shared = shared[bln])
#>              shared
#>   [1,]  1  2      9
#>   [2,]  1  3      9
#>   [3,]  1  4      9
#>   [4,]  1  5      7
#>   [5,]  1  6      7
#>   [6,]  1  7      8
#>   [7,]  1  8      7
#>   [8,]  1  9      7
#>   [9,]  1 10      6
#>  [10,]  1 11      5
#>  [11,]  1 12      8
#>  [12,]  1 14      8
#>  [13,]  1 15      7
#>  [14,]  1 16      5
#>  [15,]  1 17      7
#>  [16,]  1 18      5
#>  [17,]  1 19      5
#>  [18,]  1 20      9
#>  [19,]  2  3      8
#>  [20,]  2  4      6
#>  [21,]  2  5      7
#>  [22,]  2  6      5
#>  [23,]  2  7      9
#>  [24,]  2  8      8
#>  [25,]  2  9      7
#>  [26,]  2 10      5
#>  [27,]  2 12      8
#>  [28,]  2 13      5
#>  [29,]  2 14      9
#>  [30,]  2 15      6
#>  [31,]  2 16      6
#>  [32,]  2 17      9
#>  [33,]  2 19      6
#>  [34,]  2 20      8
#>  [35,]  3  4      6
#>  [36,]  3  6      5
#>  [37,]  3  7      6
#>  [38,]  3  8      6
#>  [39,]  3  9      6
#>  [40,]  3 10      5
#>  [41,]  3 12      6
#>  [42,]  3 14      6
#>  [43,]  3 15      6
#>  [44,]  3 16      5
#>  [45,]  3 17      5
#>  [46,]  3 20      7
#>  [47,]  4  5      5
#>  [48,]  4  7      6
#>  [49,]  4  8      7
#>  [50,]  4  9      7
#>  [51,]  4 12      6
#>  [52,]  4 14      7
#>  [53,]  4 18      5
#>  [54,]  4 20      8
#>  [55,]  5  6      5
#>  [56,]  5  7      7
#>  [57,]  5  8      5
#>  [58,]  5  9      6
#>  [59,]  5 12      5
#>  [60,]  5 14      7
#>  [61,]  5 17      7
#>  [62,]  5 18      5
#>  [63,]  5 19      5
#>  [64,]  5 20      5
#>  [65,]  6 10      6
#>  [66,]  6 14      7
#>  [67,]  6 16      5
#>  [68,]  6 17      6
#>  [69,]  7  8      8
#>  [70,]  7  9      7
#>  [71,]  7 11      6
#>  [72,]  7 12      8
#>  [73,]  7 13      7
#>  [74,]  7 14      6
#>  [75,]  7 15      6
#>  [76,]  7 16      6
#>  [77,]  7 17      7
#>  [78,]  7 18      5
#>  [79,]  7 19      8
#>  [80,]  7 20      9
#>  [81,]  8  9      8
#>  [82,]  8 10      6
#>  [83,]  8 12      6
#>  [84,]  8 13      6
#>  [85,]  8 14      8
#>  [86,]  8 17      7
#>  [87,]  8 20      9
#>  [88,]  9 10      6
#>  [89,]  9 12      5
#>  [90,]  9 14      6
#>  [91,]  9 17      5
#>  [92,]  9 20      7
#>  [93,] 10 14      6
#>  [94,] 10 16      5
#>  [95,] 10 17      7
#>  [96,] 10 20      6
#>  [97,] 11 14      5
#>  [98,] 11 18      5
#>  [99,] 11 20      5
#> [100,] 12 14      6
#> [101,] 12 15      5
#> [102,] 12 18      5
#> [103,] 12 19      5
#> [104,] 12 20      5
#> [105,] 13 17      5
#> [106,] 13 20      7
#> [107,] 14 16      6
#> [108,] 14 17      9
#> [109,] 14 18      8
#> [110,] 14 19      5
#> [111,] 14 20      8
#> [112,] 15 20      5
#> [113,] 16 17      6
#> [114,] 16 20      6
#> [115,] 17 18      5
#> [116,] 17 19      6
#> [117,] 17 20      8
#> [118,] 18 19      6
#> [119,] 18 20      5
#> [120,] 19 20      6


An approach using inner_join that summarizes the listed features with state == 1 and equal or over 5 matches.
dat_spl <- split(dat, dat$sample)

library(dplyr)

do.call(rbind, apply(combn(seq_along(dat_spl), 2), 2, \(x) 
  inner_join(dat_spl[[x[1]]] %>% filter(state == 1), 
             dat_spl[[x[2]]] %>% filter(state == 1), c("feature", "state")) %>%
    filter(n() >= 5) %>% 
    mutate(N = n(), state = NULL))) %>% 
    summarize(feature = list(feature), .by = c(sample.x, sample.y, N))

output
    sample.x sample.y N                                   feature
1         s1      s10 6               f6, f10, f11, f12, f15, f17
2         s1      s11 5                     f1, f3, f11, f13, f17
3         s1      s12 8       f1, f2, f3, f10, f11, f16, f19, f20
4         s1      s14 8        f1, f2, f4, f6, f11, f12, f15, f19
...
117       s5       s9 6                 f4, f6, f8, f16, f17, f19
118       s7       s8 8        f2, f5, f7, f8, f10, f17, f18, f19
119       s7       s9 7            f5, f7, f8, f10, f16, f17, f19
120       s8       s9 8        f4, f5, f7, f8, f10, f11, f17, f19

